# How to resize an UIImaveView based on its image?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I want to have an `UIImageView` fill a container as much as possible but the picture inside it should keep its aspect ratio and the container should fit the size of the picture inside it.

Here is a picture of how it is right now when it won't work:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nciki.jpg

I have solved the problem, but only when first loading the view, when I change the image of the imageView it gets smaller and smaller.

I solved it with this extension:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-an-aspect-fit-images-size-inside-an-image-view

So when getting an `UIImage`, I call the layout method to layout my UIViews, then I set up the image inside the UIImageView. Next, in the drawing method of the parent UIView, I calculate the `contentClippingRect` of the `UIImageView` and then set the constraints of the `UIImageView` to `contentClippingRect` and layout again.

My Layout method resets the constraints of the `UIImageView` to the constraints of the whole container when there is no image inside of the imageView.

But as said, when I change the picture it won't work and I have constraints issues when changing the image.

Here is what I tried:

```
var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        photoView.image = nil
        layout()
        photoView.image = image
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if photoView.image != nil {
        setPictureFrame()
        layout()
    }
}

private func setPictureFrame() {
    let photoRect = photoView.contentClippingRect
    photoView.clearConstraints()

    photoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoRect.height).isActive = true
    photoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoRect.width).isActive = true
}

private func layout() {

    var layoutConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    if photoView.image == nil {
        photoView.clearConstraints()
        photoView.constraintsFillWhole(view: photoViewContainer)
    }

    layoutConstraints += [
        photoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
        photoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoViewContainer.centerYAnchor),
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(layoutConstraints)
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you give example of expected behaviour as well?

Comment: The expected behaviour should be like in the image, bute the border of the UIimageView should be on the image

Answer (score 2):

You can make aspect to fit from storyboard as well. Go to attribute inspector of that imageView you will find content mode from there. here is an example[image]

you can do this programatically as well.

for swift

```
yourImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill // or you can use .scaleToFill
```

for objective c

```
yourimageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Followings are some contentModes that you can use programatically.

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,     
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,   
UIViewContentModeRedraw,             
UIViewContentModeCenter,              
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
```

Comment: Yes I know, and I use this, but the ImageView needs to get the size of it’s image, because of the border of the imageView.

Comment: are you setting constraints for its height or width?

Comment: when calling setpictureframe() and in layout when image == nil the uiview will get the frame of the container